# Recursive variadic function template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to write a class method that takes a template parameter pack, but zero arguments, and "iterate" over the types:

```
struct Bar {
    template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    void foo() {
        // something with T that involves Bar's members
        foo<Ts...>();
    }
};
```

What is the preferred way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
struct Bar {
    template <typename... Ts>
    void foo() {
        int dummy[] = {0 /*Manage case where Ts is empty*/,
                       (bar<Ts>(), void() /* To avoid overload `operator,` */, 0)...};
        (void) dummy; // suppress warning for unused variable.
    }

    template <typename T>
    void bar()
    {
        // something with T that involves Bar's members
    }

};
```

In C++17, it can be simplified with Folding expression:

```
struct Bar {
    template <typename... Ts>
    void foo() {
        (static_cast<void>(bar<Ts>()), ...);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void bar()
    {
        // something with T that involves Bar's members
    }

};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class...Fs>
void do_in_order(Fs&&...fs) {
  int _[]={0, ( std::forward<Fs>(fs)(), void(), 0 )...};
  (void)_;
}
```

hides the syntax required to execute a pack of function objects in left to right order.

Then:

```
struct Bar {
  template <class... Ts>
  void foo() {
    do_in_order([&]{
      using T = Ts;
      // code 
    }...);
  }
};
```

and in a conforming compiler, we will run the `// code` with `T` being each type from left to right.

Note that some compilers claiming to be C++11 compilers may fail to compile the above.

The advantage of this technique is that it hides the nasty "expand and evaluate templates" code within a function with a clear name.  You write `do_in_order` once, and it usually suffices for almost every use of that array-expansion trick.

There are a two important reasons to use this kind of esoteric syntax instead of the "more simple" recursive solutions.

First, it makes things easier for the optimizer.  Optimizers sometimes give up after a pile of recursive calls.

Second, the sum of the lengths names of the function signatures for the traditional recursive functions grow at O(n^2).  If you use helper types, the total length of the names is also O(n^2).  Unless you are careful, this can cause compile time, link time, and binary size bloat.

In C++1z there are plans for some "fold" syntax that may make the esoteric parts of the above less esoteric.

Comment: This is pretty neat. Apparently, gcc 4.9.2 is one of those "compilers claiming to be C++11 compilers" that fails to compile it.

Comment: @Barry ayep.  Clang I think works.  For some reason, gcc thinks that an unexpanded parameter pack at the end of a statement is an error.  Silly gcc: statements can be just one part of an expansion pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I like overloaded functions and using a typelist:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename ...Ts> struct typelist { };

void foo_impl(typelist<> )
{
  // we are finished
}

template <typename T, typename ...Ts>
void foo_impl(typelist<T, Ts...> )
{
  std::cout << typeid(T).name() << ", ";
  foo_impl(typelist<Ts...>{});
}



template <typename ...Ts>
void foo()
{
  std::cout << "called with <";
  foo_impl(typelist<Ts...>{});
  std::cout << ">" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
  foo<int, char, float>();
}
```

Comment: huh? `foo` takes no arguments.

Comment: As a downside, it requires N recursive steps for N types, and instantiates types and functions whose name length sums to O(N^2).  Doing the above with N modestly large causes slow compilation, and can lead to binary bloat if those names aren't stripped by the compiler.